# 'tx_no' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'

Tags: vb.net

I got a error about coverting string to form object.
These code I use them to covert string to form but I want to call "quiz_back" its "tx_no" textbox but it got a error.
Any suggestion?

```
Dim frm As Form
Dim formName As String = "quiz_back"
formName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name & "." & formName
frm = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(formName)), Form)
MsgBox(frm.tx_no.Text)'error
MsgBox(quiz_back.tx_no.Text)'work
```

Comment: I answered below, but I'd appreciate an explanation of what your end goal is. There may be alternative ways to achieve what you want to do without reflection.

Comment: ok. to emphasize what I wrote below, if you declare a variable of type Form, you can only call the methods that belong to the Form class (such as Show), not its subclasses, which is what quick_back is.

Comment: Is there any ways to achieve the idea?

Comment: If I knew your end goal, I could help you more. The best you can do with this code is Show the form, and allow the code inside your form_load do whatever you need to, rather than try to call a property of the form from the calling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting the variable back to its base type: Form, which does not contain those properties. Either remove the cast, or cast it to the correct type.